# Self referencing children not attached

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I have a family tree like that:

```
class Family
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Family
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Family", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Family", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    // [...]
}
```

I'm trying to `findAll()` and get the parent and children attached

```
$familyRepo = $this->em->getRepository(Family::class);
$families = $familyRepo->findAll();
foreach ($families as $family) {
    dump($family->getParent()->getName());
}
```

I can see the parents name dumped and only one query executed, so they are well attached.

However if I try to show the children:

```
    dump($family->getChildren()->count());
```

I'm seeing as much queries as there are families.

How can I get the children attached as the parents are ? (without more queries)

What am I forgetting ?

Answer (score 0):

On the one-to-many relation for `$children` you can specify to fetch objects eagerly as follows:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Family", mappedBy="parent", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $children;
```

See also the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetomany) for other params.

Comment: I'd like the children not to be eagerly fetched all the time. Besides I did tried that but certain families are still loaded with additional queries.

Comment: Then in your FamilyRepository you need to add a `findAllSomething` method where you add your query joining the `children` relation in order to fetch them in a single query. When you want that you'll use such finder and not the common `findAll` to save on queries.

Comment: That's an idea, I didn't though of that. I'll give it a try

Comment: After thinking, I suspect it'll only load the first level of children. And I suspect it is the reason why everything is not eagerly loaded too. But I'll do some investigations about it

Answer (score 0):

Following @dlondero's suggestion, I forced the deep fetch into the repository.

Here is how I did:

```
public function getRootNodes($eagerLevels = 5)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('entity0')
        ->select('partial entity0.{id, name, parent}')
        ->where('entity0.parent IS NULL')
    ;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $eagerLevels; $i++) {
        $qb
            ->leftJoin('entity'.$i.'.children', 'entity'.($i+1))
            ->addSelect('partial entity'.($i+1).'.{id, name, parent}')
        ;
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This partially fetches just what I need so no lazy loading happens.
I also made the level of deepness configurable.